# Selenium newcomer - not picking up a drop down menu

Tags: selenium

I have written this piece of code for a page which I am trying to automate but struggling to progress with. I have no doubt I have made an error as I am very inexperienced with Java. The first line works and allows me to select the checkbox but from there it doesnt seem to pick up anything else. The last three lines of the code also work. I assume its the way Im referencing the drop downs. Any help would be appreciated.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("IsImmediate")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("FollowUpType"))).selectByVisibleText("Call Back");
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Preference"))).selectByVisibleText("Mobile");
//new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("OnDate"))).selectByVisibleText("19/09/2013");
//new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("OnTime"))).selectByVisibleText("Morning");
//new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("HourlySlot"))).selectByVisibleText("11:00");
driver.findElement(By.id("Note")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("Note")).sendKeys("Callback complete");
driver.findElement(By.id("submitButton")).click();
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, but I'm guessing that your selectors are wrong.  In your HTML, is the element with the ID of `FollowUpType` a `<select>` element?

Comment: Im not 100% sure. The html is part of PEGA PRPC so again Im not great with that. The Label states FollowUptype but the box containing the drop down references a .category property.

Comment: Can you paste the HTML here?

Answer (score -1):

Are you passing the right select id and the text value? Did you try selectByValue instead?

Comment: wrong. He really needs a Select object for that. See the javadoc: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html

Comment: my bad. you need the new Select since Select is a seperate class.